# Classmethod vs Singleton in Python

Tags: python, singleton, class-method

In Python is @classmethod equivalent to creating a singleton?
Why does @classmethod ensure that only 1 instance of the class would be in use, and I wouldn't be able to create a second instance?

I dont understand why it is similar to a singleton; A singleton creates a single instance of 1 class; but if I can create several instances of the same class when a classmethod is involved, then it is not similar.. Can you delve into the similarity aspects.

Comment: classmethod isn't equivalent to creating a singleton.

Comment: oh well, do you mind explaining the difference?

Comment: classmethods act on the class, not on an instance of the class, so in that sense it is similar to the singleton pattern where there is only one instance. But classmethods do not prevent you from creating multiple instances.

Comment: Thank you; I dont understand why it is similar to a singleton; A singleton creates a single instance of 1 class;  but if I can create several instances of the same class when a classmethod is involved, then it is not similar.. Can you delve into the similarity aspects ? thnks

Comment: The only similarity I can think of is that Python implements classes by maintaining a single reference to a class object for each class loaded in memory. 

The @classmethod decorator modifies a function to be a descriptor that when called is passed a reference to this class object. It can be convenient to access the class object in this way (e.g. to call methods). However, this class object does not function in the same way as a single instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton is a creativo al pattern used to create a single instance from a class. Classmethods are a way to create alternatives constructor, a bit like in C++ with explicit constructors.

Now I want to say that in python it is not really necessary to have singleton pattern, it’s hard to make it thread safe and also can be achieved with the use of modules, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929033/using-module-as-a-singleton-in-python-is-that-ok) a really good explanation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34527297)

Comment: Of course, I understand what you’re saying. But if you read carefully I provide a link on and additional information that is not required from the question, is an addition. I will fix that of course ASAP anyway thank you for your feedback